# Getting intermittent 400 Bad Request error

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver

I recently moved my website over from AWS to an Ubuntu server on Digital Ocean. I did this with a number of other websites - couple of Wordpress blogs, a simple static site, and this one, which is also a simple static site.

All of the other websites are fine, but for this one I'm getting the error 400 Bad Request (nginx) intermittently, even though I'm using Apache as the web server.

The Apache config is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.mysite.com.conf` and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com

    ServerAdmin hi@me.ie
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mysite.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The website is a single page static site (index.html) that lives in `/var/www/html/www.mysite.com/`

The DNS is:

`A - @ - 12.345.67.89` (not real)

`CNAME - www - mysite.com`

I see nothing at all in the logs (`/var/log/apache2/*.log`) when the 400 occurs, and all the normal stuff when it loads successfully. There appears to be no pattern as to when it works or doesn't - www or no www, browser, sometimes when I refresh lots of times it loads, sometimes it loads partially with the assets/images not loading (giving a 400).

Comment: Aren't you using any load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out unbeknownst to me there was a domain redirect in place, in addition to the A record. Seems to be the cause of the strange behaviour.